# MySQL - Where clause for Date Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
select count(*) from sl_list 
where type = 'pantry'
```

which returns thousands of rows that looks like this:

```
    uuid     type      create_dtime               mod_dtime
 124234525   pantry     2012-06-13 15:25:58       2012-06-13 15:27:51
```

I want to adjust the query so that there is another where clause that states:

```
select count(*) from sl_list 
where type = 'pantry'
and "if create_dtime and mod_dtime are not the same day (i dont care about hours)"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from sl_list 
where type = 'pantry'
and date(create_dtime) <> date(mod_dtime)
```